# Permission issue while building Docker image with Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: docker, jenkins, gradle

While building the image in Jenkins gradle build fails with the error

```
ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: /opt/java/openjdk

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.
```

Following is the part of the Dockerfile. The RUN gradle build is what fails.

```
FROM gradle:7.4.2-jdk8 as builder

COPY --chown=gradle:gradle . /home/gradle/src
WORKDIR /home/gradle/src
RUN gradle build --no-daemon
```

What I have checked

1. That the path is correct /opt/java/openjdk
   https://hub.docker.com/layers/gradle/library/gradle/jdk8-jammy/images/sha256-8fe6aa6c268162cbb00e0873e94e8c8a49aea1d3bdf7a3c7499751f227f5dfc6?context=explore
2. What fails is the following gradle check : https://github.com/marklogic-community/ml-gradle/blob/9816f8756e8a6c656cb2371a4d9f85405e39e6d8/gradlew#L73

```
 if [ ! -x "$JAVACMD" ] ; then
        die "ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: $JAVA_HOME
Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation."
    fi
```

3. It builds perfectly fine locally when do I skaffold build with local profile. But fails in Jenkins.
4. So the path exists so I am not sure why the -x check fails and only in Jenkins. It is executable by the user and group -> gradle:1000:1000 - that comes with the image : gradle:7.4.2-jdk8

I would appreciate any insight to this issue. Thank you.

Comment: The only logical explanation is that the environment variable JAVA_HOME is not getting set. Can you show us how this is executed through Jenkins?

Comment: The error message that gradle prints it actually gets the value of /opt/java/openjdk from $JAVA_HOME as shown in the above snippet. 

die "ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: $JAVA_HOME

Comment: I missed it. In that case $JAVA_HOME/bin/java is not a executable.

Comment: As for containers used in Jenkins pipeline, it is defined as a kubernetes agent
For brevity I am just highlighting some aspects
pipeline {
 agent {
                kubernetes {
                defaultContainer 'skaffold'
                yamlFile 'pod.yaml'
                }
            }
  }

- Pod definition contains 2 containers skaffold and dind

Comment: "In that case $JAVA_HOME/bin/java is not a executable" -> Not sure what you mean ? :) It builds fine locally. The check that fails is indeed -x but not sure why only in Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

same issue with TeamCity agent. It runs docker-in-docker.
In container (DockerInDocker) `test -x $JAVA_HOME/bin/java` returns 1.
In agent `test -x $JAVA_HOME/bin/java` returns 0.

0777 mode, root owner as well.

Answer (score 0):

Also seeing the same issue in Jenkins running on k8s. Using `eclipse-temurin:11.0.15_10-jdk` as the base image. Checking the Java executable before gradlew is called give me:

```
13:34:46  Step 9/23 : RUN ls -la /opt/java/openjdk/bin/java
13:34:46   ---> Running in d7a82558e4b2
13:34:47  -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 12768 Apr 19 21:38 /opt/java/openjdk/bin/java
```

but when I test for executable perms I get:

```
13:24:57  Step 10/22 : RUN test -x $JAVA_HOME/bin/java
13:24:57   ---> Running in 20dd8d832464
13:24:57  The command '/bin/sh -c test -x $JAVA_HOME/bin/java' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

It looks like commands are being run as root as well:

```
13:19:06  Step 10/21 : RUN id -u -n
13:19:06   ---> Running in 1ea36050bc88
13:19:06  root
```

What makes it weirder is that I'm able to manually create the same Jenkins pod used for builds, exec in and clone the repo and build the Docker image successfully with no issues.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).